# How is Omit checked during compile time in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

I'm failing to understand why this piece of code works when using the [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type:

```js
type Foo = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

const foo: Foo = {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2'
}

console.log(foo) // {"prop1": "prop1", "prop2": "prop2"}

type Bar = Omit<Foo, 'prop2'> & {
    prop3: string;
}

const bar: Bar = {
    ...foo,
    prop3: 'prop3'
}

console.log(bar) // {"prop1": "prop1", "prop2": "prop2", "prop3": "prop3"}
```

Meanwhile, using `Bar` directly fails as expected:

```js
const qux: Bar = {
    prop1: "prop1",
    prop2: "prop2", // '{ prop1: string; prop2: string; prop3: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Bar'
    prop3: "prop3"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) only happens on properties in object literals, and only in some circumstances.  Excess properties are not really a type safety issue; the compiler only warns about them if it thinks the code is likely to immediately forget about them.  Something like `const x: {a: string} = {a: "", b: ""}` is a problem because nothing will be able to access that `b` property safely.  But `const y = {a: "", b: ""}; const x: {a: string} = y;` is fine because `y` remembers `b` even if `x` forgets it.

Again, in general, extra properties are not a type safety issue.  You *want* the compiler to allow extra properties, otherwise interface extension wouldn't work (if `interface Foo {a: string}` and `interface Bar extends Foo {b: string}`, then forbidding extra properties would mean that `Bar` is not compatible with `Foo`, and TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) would be defeated).  TypeScript doesn't really have "exact types" the way Flow does.  There's an open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) to support exact types, but right now we don't have them.  All we have is structural subtyping where `{a: string, b: string}` is assignable to `{a: string}`, and excess property checking which sometimes issues a warning about that, in very specific situations.

---

In the initializer to `bar` you are spreading `foo`, an already-existing variable.  It's not an object literal, and therefore there is no excess property checking.  This is working as intended as per [ms/TS#41237](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41237).

On the other hand, your initializer for `qux` is adding excess properties directly in an object literal, which does issue a warning, because nothing will remember that `qux` has a `prop2` property.