# why does the nullish coalescing operator removing one part of the union of records

Tags: typescript

I've been scratching my head without finding an answer. I don't understand why the nullish coalescing operator removes one part of the union in the following snippet:

```
declare const thing:
  | { id: number; version: number; label: string }
  | {
      label: string;
    }
  | undefined;

// it yields {label: string} | null instead of the expected { id: number; version: number; label: string } | { label: string; } | null
const thingWithCoallesce = thing ?? null;
```

I created a playground [to demonstrate the case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3hgFgSxQHMAuAKHngB94BvePYY+FAVwFsAjEGAbngDduaPKiatO3PtC4QmmGAULwAvuSq01FCtJCz48xT00q11FilAAzAiGBHSAegfwA7jgCe9NNhwJWECDw0HEQkKAgQNDBFeCQAB24oDCQYeDg2JH4Y1AQ42CwkSx8EcxEUeAB+UmR0LFxFAHU8XABhMIDIsAQAXh8YiormFgCjJy0KAD0q0jwigAp6ongAQl7-CHgAMk34ACIGXfpyxcIASg0KGrQkCIA6CCRCBfwiW4Z9JKDrSKGJGFOjKoZvMTk1Wu0IlEEKshgEtjt9sBDgQ+kQwTg2uFIV1zjQ1FcbiB7o9no1mhiIZ0ie80J80N9vOIuP9AaQgA). I couldn't find anything in the issue tracker about that.

Comment: `{id: number; version: number; label: string}` is a subtype of `{label: string}`. If `X` is a subtype of `Y` then every value of type `X` is also of type `Y`; therefore `X | Y` is equivalent to `Y`. Whether or not the TS compiler actually performs *subtype reduction* and collapses `X | Y` to `Y` or leaves the union alone is an implementation detail, as described in, e.g., [ms/TS#49952](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49952). So the compiler is behaving as intended here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: (continued) Do note that your playground link has code not included in plaintext in the question so it's not part of your [mre]. It's essentially of out of scope for your question, but `in`-operator narrowing is intentionally unsound (see [comments on the implementing PR](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154825541)) so the fact that `k in o` behaves differently when `o` is seen as type `X | Y` vs type `Y` even though the two types are equivalent is a safety issue for `in` and not a correctness issue for subtype collapsing. Hope that forestalls a question about `in`.

Comment: @jcalz I see... so it is more of a happy incident that the non-null coalesced version works as I intended. I  found that I could get it to work by using `id?:never` and `version?:never` but I could not explain why. Thanks to your answer I understand it makes X *not* a subtype of Y and therefore the union is not collapsed anymore.

Comment: @jcalz no worries regarding the `in`. This is how my issue initially showed up, but I quickly understood that the root cause was upstream with the union collapsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). The compiler is performing *subtype reduction*, which it can do whenever it "wants" to; see [microsoft/TypeScript#49952](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49952) for more information.

---

Let's give these types names.  Your code is essentially identical to:

```
interface Base {
  label: string
}

interface Subtype extends Base {
  id: number;
  version: number;
}

declare const thing: Subtype | Base | undefined
// const thing: Base | Subtype | undefined

const thingWithCoallesce = thing ?? null;
// const thingWithCoallesce: Base | null
```

For our purposes, the type `Subtype` is equivalent to `{id: number; version: number; label: string}`, while the type `Base` is equivalent to `{label: string}`.

---

The type `Subtype` is a *subtype* of `Base` (hence the naming); every value of type `Subtype` is also a value of type `Base`:

```
const s: Subtype = { id: 1, version: 2, label: "abc" };
const b: Base = s; // okay
```

(Note that [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) sometimes confuses people into thinking otherwise; see [How is Omit checked during compile time in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72819923/2887218) for more information).

And that means that the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Subtype | Base` is equivalent to `Base`.  You can see that from following some rules about unions like: `X extends (X | Y)` and: if `X extends Z` and `Y extends Z` then `(X | Y) extends Z`.  So `(Subtype | Base) extends Base` and `Base extends (Subtype | Base)` and thus they are equivalent.  Of course TypeScript's type system isn't fully [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) so sometimes "equivalent" things can behave differently in some situations.

---

Okay, so `Subtype | Base` and `Base` are equivalent types.  And so the compiler may, whenever it wants, perform *subtype reduction* and actually collapse `Subtype | Base` to `Base`.  It is effectively an implementation detail of the compiler whether and when it "wants" to perform subtype reduction.  It happens that when you explicitly create the union it tends to stick around where you've defined it:

```
declare const thing: Subtype | Base | undefined
// const thing: Base | Subtype | undefined
```

But switching/[narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) operations like nullish coalescing tend to reduce the unions:

```
const thingWithCoallesce = thing ?? null;
// const thingWithCoallesce: Base | null
```

---

If this is undesirable behavior, then you should probably change your types so that "every `Subtype` is a valid `Base`" doesn't apply.  If by `{label: string}` you meant "has a `label` but *lacks* an `id` and a `version`", then you will need to say so explicitly:

```
interface OtherSubtype extends Base {
  id?: never;
  version?: never;
}

declare const thing: Subtype | OtherSubtype | undefined
// const thing: Subtype | OtherSubtype | undefined

const thingWithCoallesce = thing ?? null;
// const thingWithCoallesce: Subtype | OtherSubtype | null
```

And the subtype reduction doesn't happen because neither `Subtype` nor `OtherSubtype` are subtypes of the other.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ko1BFVl1hL7e4MC69sDDioqOcBdchfdHqRSW8Pl8fkmtgDI-L6+GcxhQeNoFATFAAIS2JhAA)